# estou tentando mostra de 1 até 10 no visualg,mas está dando erro em 1 linha onde teoricamente está tudo certo

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

```
Algoritmo "SUPER CONTADOR"
//  

Var
   N1,cont : Inteiro

Inicio

  repita

    escreval ("===================") 

    escreval("|     MENU        |")
    escreval ("===================")
    escreval ("| [1] De 1 até 10 |")
    escreval ("| [2] De 10 até 1 |")
    escreval ("| [3] Sair        |")
    escreval ("===================")
    leia (N1)
    cont <- 1
    enquanto(cont < 10) faca <- o visualg está endentificando o erro nessa linha
      escreva (cont)
     cont <- cont + 1
    fimenquanto
  ate (N1 = 3)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Erro na linha 1 ou há erro em alguma linha ? O VisualG não usa ponto e virgula ";"?

Comment: Não tenho certeza do erro não consigo testar o código no momento. Parece que o laço de repetição não usa parenteses "()" na expressão.
Ex `enquanto cont < 10 faca` em vez de `enquanto (cont < 10) faca`

[Apoio informática](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/item/14-comandos-de-repeticao)

Comment: era o parenteses mesmo valeu ai pessoal :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu troquei o `enquanto` pelo `repita` e adicionei a estrutura de repetição: `escolha-caso-fimescolha`.

```
Var c,n,cont:inteiro

Inicio
cont <- 1
repita
      escreval("                 ")
      escreval("|===============|")
      escreval("|     MENU      |")
      escreval("|===============|")
      escreval("|===============|")
      escreval("| [1] de 1 a 10 |")
      escreval("| [2] de 10 a 1 |")
      escreval("| [3] para sair |")
      escreval("=================")
      leia(n)
      escolha (n)
      caso 1
           n <- 1
           c <- 1
           repita
                 escreva(c)
                 c <- c + 1
           ate(c > 10)
      caso 2
           n <- 2
           c <- 10
      repita
            escreva(c)
            c <- c - 1
            ate(c < 1)
      caso 3
           n <- 3
           se (n > 2) entao
           cont <- cont + 1
           fimse
      fimescolha
ate(cont > 1)
limpatela
escreva("Saindo...")
```